# Unable to spyOn imported function in compose block under componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme, recompose

Having some issues using spyOn for testing a method call inside my compose() block for my Reactjs app using recompose, redux, etc.

Basic layout is this:

```
// index.jsx
import { foo, baz } from './lib';
const enhance = compose(
  foo(),
  lifecycle({
      componentDidMount() {
        baz();
      }
  });
);
export const MyComp = (...);
const mapStateToProps = state => (...);
export connect(mapStateToProps)(enhance(MyComp));

// lib.js
export const foo = () => {
  lifecycle({
      componentDidMount() {
        bar();
      }
  });
}
export const bar = () => {};
export const baz = () => {};

//index.test.jsx
import * as lib from '.libs';

describe('Test', () => {
  const didMountSpy = jest.spyOn(MyComp.prototype, 'componentDidMount');
  const fooSpy = jest.spyOn(lib, 'foo');
  const barSpy = jest.spyOn(lib, 'bar');
  const bazSpy = jest.spyOn(lib, 'baz');

  const wrapper = mount(<MyComp ... />);

  expect(didMountSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // PASS
  expect(bazSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // PASS
  expect(fooSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // FAIL
  expect(barSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // FAIL
});
```

Strange part for me is if you look at **baz()**, I'm able to successfully expect the function call when it's not wrapped in another method in compse(). But I'm not able to expect **foo(), bar()**. My suspicion is that there is some weirdness with how enzyme/jest mocks the Reactjs lifecycle methods.

Has anyone one run into anything similar and have solutions to get spyOn to work for the nested methods under lifecycle.componentDidMount()?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to use `jest.mock` method for mocking imports

Follow these steps:

- Create a folder named `__mocks__` in the same folder where lib.js is located
- Create a file named lib.js in `__mocks__` folder and provide a mock implementation for `foo`, `bar` and `baz` methods/components
- In index.test.jsx do not import lib.js. Also, before you import index.js in index.test add the following line

`jest.mock('path-to-lib/lib.js')`

Refer: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks

Answer (score 0):

**fooSpy**

`fooSpy` isn't called because `foo` gets called when `enhance` gets created which happens right when `index.jsx` is imported so `foo` has already been called by the time it gets wrapped in a spy to create `fooSpy`.

If you want to capture that `foo` was called you will need to delay the creation of `enhance`.

**barSpy**

`bar()` is defined locally in `lib.js` and it is being called directly within the definition of `foo`.

`jest.spyOn` replaces the *module export* of `bar`.  Because the definition of `foo` is using `bar` directly and not the module export of `bar`, replacing the module export of `bar` with a spy does not affect the call within `foo` and `barSpy` is never called.

If you want to capture that `bar` was called you will need to use the *module export* of `bar` within the definition of `foo`.

---

Here is a working version of the test:

lib.js

```jsx
import { lifecycle } from 'recompose';
import * as self from './lib';  // import the module into itself

export const foo = () =>
  lifecycle({
      componentDidMount() {
        self.bar();  // call the module export for bar()
      }
  });
export const bar = () => {};
export const baz = () => {};
```

---

index.jsx

```jsx
import * as React from 'react';
import { compose, lifecycle } from 'recompose';

import { foo, baz } from './lib';

export class MyComp extends React.Component {
  render() { return (<div>My Comp</div>); }
}

// use a function to delay the creation of enhance()
export const initialize = () => {
  const enhance = compose(
    foo(),
    lifecycle({
        componentDidMount() {
          baz();
        }
    })
  );
  return enhance(MyComp);
}
```

---

index.test.jsx

```jsx
import * as React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

import * as lib from './lib';
import { initialize } from './index';

test('MyComp', () => {
  const fooSpy = jest.spyOn(lib, 'foo');
  const barSpy = jest.spyOn(lib, 'bar');
  const bazSpy = jest.spyOn(lib, 'baz');

  const MyComp = initialize();  // this will create enhance() which will call foo()
  const didMountSpy = jest.spyOn(MyComp.prototype, 'componentDidMount');

  const wrapper = mount(<MyComp />);

  expect(didMountSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // PASS
  expect(bazSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // PASS
  expect(fooSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // PASS
  expect(barSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // PASS
});
```